# Is there a way to get a stack trace whenever new is called in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, gcc, valgrind

I have a long-running C++ program that is usually compiled with gcc (g++). I have used valgrind to verify that there are no memory leaks, so I am not looking for a leak detector.

What I am concerned with, though, are memory fragmentation and unnecessary new / delete pairs on temporary buffers / objects.

Is there a way to log all calls to new (even if they happen inside STL containers), providing a stack trace so that I can hunt them down in my code? I tried mtrace, but that only applies to C++ - it ends up saying that all allocations are happening in the global new allocator when I look up the responsible line of code. Somehow, valgrind's memcheck is able to do almost what I want in that it shows stack traces of memory allocations. Unfortunately, it seems that they are only rendered for allocations without matching deallocations.

Comment: Maybe, some answers from this question about leak detection may help you. I think "leak detection" and "allocation logging" are something quite connected things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761125/gcc-memory-leak-detection-equivalent-to-microsoft-crtdbg-h

Comment: Have you looked into instrumenting your code? See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graphvis/ for example. I know that is not a complete description for how to solve your specific problem, but maybe this gives you a hint how to obtain your stack traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted [Nik B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11062088/6160) for pointing me in the right direction, and here's what I actually did using `libunwind` instead, since the linked stack trace suggestion can only get function names for linked libraries. This code is available on GitHub at https://github.com/landtuna/opnew-stacktraces

newdelete.cpp:

```
#include <exception>
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "stacktrace.hpp"

void* operator new (size_t size) {
  void* p = malloc(size);

  if (p == 0) {
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }

  std::cout << "allocated " << size << std::endl;
  printTrace(std::cout);

  return p;
}

void operator delete (void* p) {
  free(p);
}
```

stacktrace.cpp:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <libunwind.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

#include "stacktrace.hpp"

void printTrace(ostream& out) {
  unw_cursor_t cursor;
  unw_context_t context;

  unw_getcontext(&context);
  unw_init_local(&cursor, &context);

  while (unw_step(&cursor) > 0) {
    unw_word_t offset, pc;
    char fname[200];
    size_t demangledSize = 200;
    char* demangled = (char*) malloc(demangledSize);

    unw_get_reg(&cursor, UNW_REG_IP, &pc);
    fname[0] = '\0';
    unw_get_proc_name(&cursor, fname, sizeof(fname), &offset);

    int status;

    char *ret = abi::__cxa_demangle(fname, demangled, &demangledSize, &status);
    if (ret) {
      // return value may be a realloc() of the input
      demangled = ret;
    }
    else {
      // demangling failed, just pretend it's a C demangled with no args
      strncpy(demangled, fname, demangledSize);
      strncat(demangled, "()", demangledSize);
      demangled[demangledSize-1] = '\0';
    }

    out << hex << demangled << "+0x" << offset << " [" << pc << "]" << dec << '\n';
    free(demangled);
  }
  out << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always override the global new/delete functions thusly, if you want to keep track of additional statistics about allocations:

```
void* operator new (size_t size)
{
    void *pPtr = alloc_memory(size); /* perform the allocation here but don't use new! */

    if(pPtr == 0)
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    /* additional code here to do whatever sort of tracking you want */
    return pPtr;
}

void operator delete (void *pPtr)
{
    if(pPtr == 0)
        return; // legal to call delete on NULL pointers - don't pass NULL to free()

    /* additional code to do whatever tracking you want here */
    free(pPtr); 
}
```

As for getting a backtrace, that is compiler and O/S dependent, and there's no standard way of getting to it. Since you mention GCC the following may work for you:

http://tombarta.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/c-stack-traces-with-gcc/

Comment: Actually, the correct behaviour would be to try out all `new_handler`s before throwing.

Comment: You are right. I completely forgot about that little detail! Thanks for pointing it out.