# warning for not using free() malloc

Tags: c

Are there any safeguards built into GCC that check for memory leaks? If so how can I use them? When I compile with "gcc -Wall -o run run.c", the compiler does not seem to care if any allocated heap-space is being freed at the end of the code. I could not find any simple fixes for this on Google.

Thanks much for your time.

EDIT:
Google Searches did point to Valgrind among other tools. But I was curious as to why the compiler cant deal with this issue. As a newbie, it seemed a simple enough task to check if every "malloc" has a "free" associated with it.

Comment: No safeguards in the compiler. Use valgrind or others.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.

Comment: For many cases, the compiler can't know whether allocated memory should be freed. Use Valgrind to check your exe for memory leaks.

Comment: A compiler doesn't have enough information to detect memory leaks, which occur at run time. And in some cases, `malloc()`ing memory and letting it be implicitly deallocated by the system when the program terminates is a reasonable approach.

Comment: @KeithThompson That may be a reasonable approach, but is not a good habit to get into.  It probably should only be done by an experienced developer who understands the risk

Comment: possible duplicate of [GCC memory leak detection equivalent to Microsoft crtdbg.h?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761125/gcc-memory-leak-detection-equivalent-to-microsoft-crtdbg-h)

Comment: @KeithThompson - That is a terrible approach. It gets people into the habit of not tidying up after themselves

Comment: @KeithThompson: Could you please provide an example where an implicit deallocation is better?

Comment: It's not. With the power to allocate, comes the responsibility to keep track of, and deallocate. `valgrind` is your friend and simple to use. Simply run your program through it (e.g. `valgrind ./yourprogname`)

Comment: @greywanderer: Suppose an application builds up a complex data structure using muliple calls to `malloc()` (trees of linked lists of hash tables of ...), and uses that data structure throughout its execution. Letting the OS deallocate the entire heap in one fell swoop when the program terminates is likely to be faster and less error-prone than calling `free()` for each allocated chunk of memory in just the right order.

Comment: @greywanderer - Keith makes a good and valid point, but if you are not at the level of dealing with lists of tables or trees that are from validated code where you are guaranteed not to leak, stick to tracking and deallocating the blocks of memory you create `:-)`

Comment: I agree with Keith, however one situation where you really can't leave it to the OS is when your code is going in a Windows DLL.  A program may load and unload your DLL multiple times so you do have to clean up after yourself .

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to analyze code for problems - static analysis and run-time analysis.  Static analysis reads the code - this is what compilers do really well.  Run-time analysis for code problems happens when the code is linked against another set of libraries that see what the code actually does  as it runs under surveillance.  Finding memory leaks is difficult for static analysis but not for a run-time analysis package.

Other run-time analyses are things like code coverage - does all parts of your code run?  gcov does this, like valgrind and electric fence look for memory problems like leaks.

So, no, there are no really good compiler safeguards for testing memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

There is `-fsanitize=leak` GCC flag.

It overrides `malloc`/`calloc`/`free` to make them count allocated and freed blocks of memory.
If your program is compiled with this flag, it prints information about detected leaks to the terminal after execution.

You can read about it [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/LeakSanitizer).

---

Also, I have never used it, so this answer is completely based on GCC manual.

Comment: But, that is not a compile-time test.  That is only the compiler providing support for a run-time test.  The original question asks why the _compiler_ doesn't warn about memory leaks.

Comment: @jameslarge OP haven't said anything about `compile-time`. He asked for `safeguards built into GCC that check for memory leaks`.

Comment: Perhaps the question was ambiguous.  I thought mainly of the part where the OP said, "When I compile with "gcc -Wall -o run run.c", the compiler does not seem to care if any allocated heap-space is being freed"

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't detect that a `malloc()` was missing a corresponding `free()`.