# Malloc, strlen, strcat

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

The following is a piece of code from the begining of a program that I am writing (which contains an error).

```
    char *name;
    char *name2;

    if (argn != 2) {
        printf("You have to enter the name of the input file");
        return 1;
    }

    name = malloc(strlen(arg[1]) + 1);      
    name2 = malloc(strlen(arg[1]) + 1);

    strcpy(name, arg[1]); 
    strcpy(name2, arg[1]);

    strcat(name2, "-results.pdb");
```

There is an error here which is with `strcat`, indeed `name2` does not have enough size to carry out the operation above. Yet `strcat` executes without a problem.
However later on in a completely unrelated part of the program an operation with another array that has been initialized after this `strcat` gives an error.
It is an integer array for which I am assigning values to its elements and it gives an error before I can assign all the values. I am assuming that since there is not enough memory in name2 for the operation above this "somehow" affects the next arrays that are initialized. I would like to understand:

1- What is likely happening here so that the extra information that could not be written to name2 affects other arrays declared later?

2- I probably wouldn't be able to backtrace this problem so easily in a more complicated program since error occurs elsewhere rather than in strcat. How can I prevent this kind of sneaky errors like a `memory problematic` process affecting totally unrelated arrays elsewhere?

Comment: (1) - hard to say since you didn't post the code with the problem; (2) check lengths before using `strcat` and other such functions

Comment: the code is unfortunately too long with multiple header files. May I then ask is there a code debugger that would recognize this error? cppcheck doesn`t.

Comment: there's no substitute for learning the language properly

Comment: well finding errors helps me learn but on larger codes it becomes dauntingly hard to find such errors. That is why I am asking for some tips on how to catch such errors that cause erratic behaviour.

Comment: You want to use a memory checker like Valgrind (https://valgrind.org) to detect such errors.

Comment: Valgrind is good, or you can build your own stack checker....Fill all variables on the stack with known values (like ABABABAB... in hex for example)  Then check for these known values before you use or malloc or set a variable.  This will at least highlight that corruption has occured prior to your check

Comment: @Grantly: The OP's issue is related to the heap.

Comment: @alk Thanks, you could do the same for the heap.  I will edit my answer and add a reference to a tool that does this...

Comment: @Grantly: You are suggesting to have the program fill its whole heap with a specific pattern?

Comment: @alk No not the same as the stack. With the heap - you would only fill allocated memory space... Many tools do this, although this of course grinds your program to a halt - it is useful for extreme debugging of this nature....However memory leak detectors are more sophisticated as in my edited answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Yet strcat executes without a problem.

No it doesn't. It returns, but it has planted a time bomb. As you observe later on.

What happens is **undefined behavior**. You have written to memory you were not allowed to write. Whatever was stored there is now garbage and whatever code expects to find meaningful values there is now misbehaving.
Especially if malloc internal data was corrupted the observation is random crashes when attempting to realloc or free memory later.

The correct way is to allocate the memory with

```
name2 = malloc(strlen(arg[1]) + sizeof "-results.pdb");
```

This takes care of the "+1" for the terminating NUL, since `sizeof "-results.pdb"` is 13.

Even easier is using `asprintf` (not ISO C but available on any contemporary Unix), which allocates the memory as needed:

```
asprintf(&name2, "%s-results.psb", arg[1]);
```

There! No strlen, no strcat, no sizeof, no malloc. Just an all-in-one call doing the *Right Thing*<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: Well then maybe I should ask for a reference that goes over this `undefined behaviours` so that next time I have one I know where to look. Such problems usually give me a headache as my codes grow larger and larger. What about code checkers? cppcheck doesn`t detect this for instance.

Comment: @Sina The ISO C Standard is the canonical source if you want to know all the places where undefined behavior may happen. Sadly, in general not all instances can be detected automatically. Some lints are better than others. Some commercial tools go to great length (Gimpel's FlexeLint, Mathworks' Polyspace to name two I use at work).

Comment: By undefined do you mean that some random place in memory is overwritten? It always produces the same error in the exact same place so I am assuming it is not that random or undefined? Why is it called undefined?

Comment: @Sina It is undefined because that's what the C Standard says. The definition is: *behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements. NOTE: Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).*

Comment: @Sina While you might think the behavior you observe is kind of defined, since it is repeatable, you should consider that the behavior might change drastically if you use different optimization options, the next version of the compiler, or add more code to the program. Should the Standard say what has to happen for the many ways program errors can surface? No, that's impossible. So it's left undefined.

Comment: I will flag this as the correct answer since the keyword "undefined behaviour" has provided me with many good sources on this issue upon doing some google search. For people who may wonder some are: http://insanecoding.blogspot.de/2014/06/memory-management-in-c-and-auto.html  and http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 and https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP43-C.+Avoid+undefined+behavior+when+using+restrict-qualified+pointers

Answer (score 5):

Like the manual of strcat said to you:

`char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);`

> The  strcat()  function appends the src string to the dest string,
>   overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and
>   then
>          adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result.  **If dest is
>   not large
>          enough, program behavior is unpredictable;** buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs.

So **unpredictable** means "everything may happend", your situation is a one kind of **everything**.

You should know, that everything is the real everything, so the program may crash on `strcat` call, may even work as you expected (this time), may crash somewhere else, because it's overwrited some memory used by malloc internals, for example, and now it doesn't know what to free. It depends actually on your system and where int the memory was your `char *dest`, and this may vary every time you run your program.

That's why it's always better to use `strncat`, so you can specify the buffer size, or even you can use `asprintf` for string concatenation, it will allocate as much memory for you, as it's needed.

For your example you'd write something like this:

```
char *newstr = NULL;
asprintf(&newstr, "%s%s", name2,"-results.pdb");
```

And then you'll have a pointer to new `malloc`ed string, in your `newstr`, don't forget to free it after.

Comment: That manual page should have used the technical term **undefined behavior** instead of **unpredictable**.

Comment: Well, it's from linux default `man 3 strcat`. I don't know why did they write it this way.

Comment: `asprintf` is not in ISO C

Comment: @M.M, true, but he didn't ask about strictly ISO C, all though he didn't ask about better solution at all.

Answer (score -4):

You could simply be more generous with your malloc

```
name2 = malloc(strlen(arg[1])+100);
```

This would avoid the dest size issue with `strcat`, which is overwriting an arbitrary part of memory causing you the problems later on...As other answers mention, 'undefined behaviour'...

If you can use a Microsoft C++ compiler, then a memory leak detector will help:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Add this to your header file

```
#ifdef _Windows
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "crtdbg.h"
#endif
```

Then use these functions in your code, in main, before much else:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag 
_CrtSetBreakAlloc
```

There should be alot of good resources out there, and it is simpler to use than it looks.  See this link for more variations:

[GCC memory leak detection equivalent to Microsoft crtdbg.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761125/gcc-memory-leak-detection-equivalent-to-microsoft-crtdbg-h)

Comment: This isn't a good solution, what if the code changes a bit and the data being strcatted is longer than 100?

Comment: OP didn't ask for a bad solution either

Comment: This solution is misleading since if the concataned array has dynamically allocated memory than it will still cause problems. It is also waste of memory. p.s: I actually did not ask for a solution at all, as the solution is obvious and the mistake is already pointed out by me.

Comment: @M.M but the OP wanted to understand!  I pointed out the exact reason for undefined behaviour, and showed the OP how to test for it and replicate it or eliminate it...for his/her understanding about the arbitrary memory overrun....

Comment: How about removing the "solution" from your answer then, since you agree that OP was not looking for a solution

Comment: Thanks for the renewed and informational comment, upvoted.

Comment: @Sina you're welcome.  Hope it helps, it saved me from a few nasty bugs